# A generic MVC ArrayAdapter class

Tags: java, android

I have seen the model created in this question: A generic MVC ArrayAdapter class

This is the adapter class:

```
public class MVCArrayAdapter<ModelType> extends BaseAdapter{
Activity ctx;
ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
Constructor<?> viewConstructor;

public MVCArrayAdapter(Activity context, String viewClassName) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
    super();
    ctx = context;
    viewConstructor = Class.forName(viewClassName).getConstructor(Activity.class);
}


public int getCount() {
    return array.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return array.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewRow<ModelType> view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>)convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        try {
            view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>)viewConstructor.newInstance(ctx);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    view.setModel((ModelType)getItem(position));
    return view;
}

public void add(ModelType object){
    array.add(object);
}

public void addAll(Collection<? extends ModelType> objects){
    array.addAll(objects);
}

public void addAll(ModelType... objects){
    for(ModelType object : objects){
        array.add(object);
    }
}

public void clear(){
    array.clear();
}

public void insert(ModelType object, int index){
    array.set(index, object);
}

public void remove(ModelType object){
    array.remove(object);
}

public void sort(Comparator<? super ModelType> comparator){
    Collections.sort(array, comparator);
}}
```

And the row view class:

```
    public abstract class ListViewRow<ModelType> extends FrameLayout {
ModelType model;
View childView;

public ListViewRow(Activity context, int viewLayout) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater( );
    childView = inflater.inflate( viewLayout,  this, false );
    addView(childView);
}


public abstract void setModel(ModelType newModel);}
```

Here's an example child view class that sets a text field and a image field, to show the amount of work in creating the row view:

```
  public class AdapterRow extends ListViewRow<String> {
TextView tv;
ImageView iv;

public AdapterRow(Activity context) {
    super(context, R.layout.li);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
}


public void setModel(String str){
    tv.setText(str);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}}
```

the code is good but i was trying to add a holder and didn't where should i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did the same thing that i did above but with some modifications in the MVCArray:

```
package com.code.utilities;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

public class MVCArrayAdapter<ModelType> extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Activity ctx;
    public ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
    private Constructor<?> viewConstructor;

public MVCArrayAdapter(Activity context, String viewClassName)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
    super();
    ctx = context;
    viewConstructor = Class.forName(viewClassName).getConstructor(
            Activity.class);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return array.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position >= array.size()) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();// or something more
    } // specific to your API
    return array.get(position);

}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ListViewRow<ModelType> view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>) convertView;

    try {
        final ListViewRow<ModelType> view = (ListViewRow<ModelType>) viewConstructor
                .newInstance(ctx);
        final MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        holder.childView.setModel((ModelType) getItem(position));
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public void add(ModelType object) {
    array.add(object);
}

public void addAll(Collection<? extends ModelType> objects) {
    array.addAll(objects);
}

public void addAll(ModelType... objects) {
    for (ModelType object : objects) {
        array.add(object);
    }
}

public void clear() {
    array.clear();
}

public void insert(ModelType object, int index) {
    array.set(index, object);
}

public void remove(ModelType object) {
    array.remove(object);
}

public void sort(Comparator<? super ModelType> comparator) {
    Collections.sort(array, comparator);
}

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
public class MyHolder {

    ListViewRow<ModelType> childView = null;

    public MyHolder(ListViewRow<ModelType> view) {
        this.childView = view;
    }

}}
```

thanks for your help @SinaRezaei it really inspired me !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a holder since the views you need to use for showing the model are saved inside your view class.

However, AFAIK this implementation is **not so good.** since for using the childView item, you make the OS keep reference to its parent ListViewRow item. I wonder why you don't use a recyclerView and ViewHolder instead of listview.

If you want to implement this with listView, here is my suggestion for Holder class and Adapter class.

```
private abstract class MyHolder<ModelType>
{
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {

        childView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        itemView.setTag(this);
    }

    public void showDataInView(ModelType);

    View childView;
}
```

and the Adapter class:

```
public class MVCArrayAdapter<ModelType> extends BaseAdapter{
    Activity ctx;
    ArrayList<ModelType> array = new ArrayList<ModelType>();
    Constructor<?> viewConstructor;

    public MVCArrayAdapter(Activity context, String viewClassName) throws NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
        super();
        ctx = context;
        viewConstructor = Class.forName(viewClassName).getConstructor(Activity.class);
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return array.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MyHolder<ModelType> holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate( viewLayout,  this, false );
            holder = new MyHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (MyHolder<ModelType>) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.showDataInView((ModelType)getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    public void add(ModelType object){
        array.add(object);
    }

    public void addAll(Collection<? extends ModelType> objects){
        array.addAll(objects);
    }

    public void addAll(ModelType... objects){
        for(ModelType object : objects){
            array.add(object);
        }
    }

    public void clear(){
        array.clear();
    }

    public void insert(ModelType object, int index){
        array.set(index, object);
    }

    public void remove(ModelType object){
        array.remove(object);
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<? super ModelType> comparator){
        Collections.sort(array, comparator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I don't have enought reputation to comment, I comment here.

Comment: I tried your solution kind of :

  if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate( viewLayout,  this, false );
            holder = new MyHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (MyHolder<ModelType>) convertView.getTag();
        }and didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enought reputation to comment, I add my description here. Your final implementation is **very bad** because it inflates a new view each time a listview item must be shown. It prevents android from using recycled views and creates a new view, which will result in outOfMemory exception for lists with many items containing large data. (e.g. images)

You should create a new instance of view only if your convertView is null, otherwise you should use the recycled view based on view type.

[Check this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084975/5528269)

Comment: Please elaborate with an example with RecycleView