# how to display first two value from json data

Tags: android

i have the json data like below

```
[
{
    "user": "sam",
    "comment": "jjjjjj",


},
{
    "user": "vishnu",
    "comment": "hello",


},
{
    "user": "ijas",
    "comment": "hello  bachanji ",

},
{
    "user": "kiran",
    "comment": "bye",
  }
]
```

i display all the data in recycle view using adapter, actualy i want to display the first two data that is

```
{
"user": "sam",
"comment": "jjjjjj",
}
{
"user": "vishnu",
"comment": "hello",
}
```

i fetch data using the below code

```
List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Data current= new Data();
                    current.user=json_data.getString("user");
                    current.comment= json_data.getString("comment");
                    data.add(current);
```

how can display the first two data

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: i didn't face any issue i just want to display the first two data i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: This is simple my friend just use ur logic u got lots of answer. Just google this before u ask question. This question may some duplicate

Comment: @Nithinlal sorry for late for the reply, i got answer for this

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();
int length = jArray.length() > 2 ? 2: jArray.length()
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Data current= new Data();
                    current.user=json_data.getString("user");
                    current.comment= json_data.getString("comment");
                    data.add(current);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Data> data=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
                JSONObject json_data =     jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Data current= new Data();
                    current.user=json_data.getString("user");
                current.comment=     json_data.getString("comment");
                data.add(current);
}
```

Comment: got a exception when size is less than 2 .handle that

Comment: int i = (jArray.length()>2)?2:jArray.length();

Comment: In place of 2 write n;

Comment: Its just use of ternary operator .

Comment: If you will put the whole for loop part in try catch block it won't cause error .

Comment: Rishabh @Nithinlal is so curious about this issue. I wish he could post an answer here. :-)

Comment: if u add int arraylength = (jArray.length()>2)?2:jArray.length(); there is no chance for exception. So don't put unnecessary try catch block

Comment: I was giving him an alternate option with least modification of code . Try catch comes in handy .

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can iterate the list two times and render in UI.

```
for(int i =0; i< 2; i++){
   Data current = data.get(i);//But we need to check if there is less than 2 entries
   String userName = current.user;
   String comment = current.comment;
   //Now display them
   //Also you can show them in different TextViews
   userNameTextView[i].setText(userName);
   comment[i].setText(comment);
}
```

That way you can show any number of data.

But usually we use different [Adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084883/android-inflating-listview) to show in list.

Comment: got a exception when size is less than 2 .handle that

Comment: @Nithinlal Please see the comment. Not doing all homework here.